# onkeyup event doesnt work- AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am studying Ajax and I was trying to write a simple code. But unfortunately it doesnt work. Could someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks

Code with ajax script:

```
function show(str,url,div) {
    var x;
    if(str.length==0) {
        document.getElementById("meno").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        x= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        x= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    x.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("meno").innerHTML=x.responseText;
        }

        x.open("POST",url,true);
        x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        x.send("string=str");
    }
}
<form action="registracka.php" method="post">
<table cellspacing=10px>
<tr>  
<td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="meno" onkeyup="show(this.value,ajax.php,meno)">  
</td><td><div id="meno"></div></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Script ajax.php just has to print out message OK,,, But it does nothing after typing a letter into form.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `div` parameter to the function?

Comment: I was using, but I thought that mistake is there and I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the parameters to the function that are literal strings:

```
<td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="meno" onkeyup="show(this.value, 'ajax.php', 'meno')">
```

Didn't you get errors in the Javascript console because you were trying to access an undefined variable `ajax`?

When you send the parameter, you need to concatenate the variable:

```
x.send("string=" + encodeURIComponent(str));
```

Also, your braces are wrong, so you're not sending the AJAX request in the first place. You have the code to send the request inside the callback function.

```
function show(str,url,div) {
    var x;
    if(str.length==0) {
        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        x= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        x= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    x.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=x.responseText;
        }
    }
    x.open("POST",url,true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.send("string=" + encodeURIComponent(str));
}
```

Comment: I've added a correction to how you're sending the `str` parameter to the server.

Comment: You had the code to send the AJAX request in the wrong place, which should be obvious since I added correct indentation.

Comment: Parameter has nothing common with this. Ajax.php contains just a echo "OK";

Comment: Then why are you sending `string=str`?

Comment: At first I wanted to try if it works with a simple echo. Then I wanna use this variable. That´s why I am sending it.

Comment: Anyway, does my last answer fix the problem?

Comment: Buddy,, thanks a lot. Yes it does, but the main problem was that I havent set the permissions on the server for ajax.php. So stupid.